# Get data points in web page via vba

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I need to get specific values on this webpage. How do I get just those values into Excel?

http://www.securities-administrators.ca/nrs/nrsIndvSearchResults.aspx?mode=QS&type=I&indv=david+hill

Below is the fragment of HTML content for the results, I would need the value "BOOTH, David (Arthur)" for example to be imported into Excel.

```
<div>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" class="gridview_style" id="ctl00_bodyContent_gvIndividuals" rules="all" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="width:50%;"><span id="ctl00_bodyContent_gvIndividuals_ctl01_lbl_ind">Name</span></th>
            <th scope="col" style="width:50%;">Firm(s)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="articleText">
                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$bodyContent$gvIndividuals$ctl02$lbtnIndDetail&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="ctl00_bodyContent_gvIndividuals_ctl02_lbtnIndDetail">BOOTH, David (Arthur)</a>
            </td>
            <td class="articleText"><span id="ctl00_bodyContent_gvIndividuals_ctl02_lblFirmName">SCOTIA CAPITAL INC. / SCOTIA CAPITAUX INC.</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="articleText">
                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$bodyContent$gvIndividuals$ctl03$lbtnIndDetail&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="ctl00_bodyContent_gvIndividuals_ctl03_lbtnIndDetail">HILL, David (Adam)</a>
            </td>
            <td class="articleText"><span id="ctl00_bodyContent_gvIndividuals_ctl03_lblFirmName">RBC DIRECT INVESTING INC./RBC PLACEMENTS EN DIRECT INC.</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="articleText">
                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$bodyContent$gvIndividuals$ctl04$lbtnIndDetail&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="ctl00_bodyContent_gvIndividuals_ctl04_lbtnIndDetail">HILL, David (Lowell)</a>
            </td>
            <td class="articleText"><span id="ctl00_bodyContent_gvIndividuals_ctl04_lblFirmName">STATE FARM INVESTOR SERVICES (CANADA) CO.</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below example shows how to retrieve necessary data from the webpage via XHR and RegEx:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim QueryString As String
    Dim PageURL As String
    Dim PageContent As String
    Dim Match As Variant
    Dim a() As Variant

    QueryString = "david hill"
    PageURL = "http://www.securities-administrators.ca/nrs/nrsIndvSearchResults.aspx?mode=QS&type=I&indv=" & EncodeUriComponent(QueryString)

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", PageURL, False
        .send
        PageContent = .responseText
    End With
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each Match In RegExMatches(PageContent, "<a id=""ctl00_bodyContent_gvIndividuals_ctl\d{2}_lbtnIndDetail""[^>]*>([^<]*)")
            .Item(.Count) = Match.SubMatches(0)
        Next
        a = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Items())
    End With
    Output2DArray Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), a

End Sub

Function EncodeUriComponent(strText As String) As String
    Static objHtmlfile As Object

    If objHtmlfile Is Nothing Then
        Set objHtmlfile = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        objHtmlfile.parentWindow.execScript "function encode(s) {return encodeURIComponent(s)}", "jscript"
    End If
    EncodeUriComponent = objHtmlfile.parentWindow.encode(strText)
End Function

Function RegExMatches(sText, sPattern, Optional bGlobal = True, Optional bMultiLine = True, Optional bIgnoreCase = True)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = bGlobal
        .MultiLine = bMultiLine
        .IgnoreCase = bIgnoreCase
        .Pattern = sPattern
        Set RegExMatches = .Execute(sText)
    End With
End Function

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```